# How can I implement a join using 2 expressions in Linq while accounting for nulls?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I'm trying to create a Linq query that will return an Ienumerable in .net Core.

I have 2 tables:  One that defines multiselect items for the front-end and the other that actually has the multi-selected values stored from user input.

I hit the brick wall with the Linq join that has more than one condition.  I'll hack my way through at first, but I'm hoping someone who has done what I'm doing can share with me what his/her best solution was for a SelectList.

```
[RAW SQL]
SELECT 
      ot.OrganizationTypeText
    , ot.OrganizationTypeValue
    , si.OrganizationTypeSelectedItemValue
    , CASE WHEN si.OrganizationTypeSelectedItemValue IS NULL then 0
      ELSE 1
      END AS selected 
FROM [Organization.OrganizationType] ot
LEFT JOIN [Organization.OrganizationTypeSelectedItem] si ON (si.OrganizationID = 1) 
    AND (si.OrganizationTypeSelectedItemValue = ot.OrganizationTypeValue)
ORDER BY ot.OrganizationTypeDisplayOrder

[LINQ QUERY SO FAR]
var query = from ot in _db.OrganizationType
    join si in _db.OrganizationTypeSelectedItem on ot.OrganizationTypeValue equals si
        .OrganizationTypeSelectedItemValue
    select new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = ot.OrganizationTypeText,
        Value = ot.OrganizationTypeValue.ToString(),
        Selected = (si.OrganizationTypeSelectedItemValue == null) ? false : true
    };

[DESIRED RETURN RESULTS TO WORK WITH]
Text        Value   debug   Selected
Customer        1       1          1
Partner         2    NULL          0
Donor           3       3          1
Sponsor         4       4          1
Vendor          5    NULL          0
Lead            6    NULL          0
Prospect        7    NULL          0
```

I expected this to be as easy as the raw SQL but I just discovered that Linq doesn't like multiple expressions in joins.  The null value that needs to be interpreted as a false selected item is giving me headaches on sub-selects I attempt.

Answer (score 0):

The Linq I used is in lamda expression.
My work around is to filter the OrganizationTypeSelectedItem then only join with the OrganizationType table.
Hope this will help.

```
var query = _db.OrganizationType
               .LeftJoin(
                _db.OrganizationTypeSelectedItem.Where(si=>si.OrganizationID == 1),
                orgType => orgType.OrganizationTypeValue,
                orgSI => orgSi.OrganizationTypeSelectedItemValue,
                (orgType, orgSI) => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = orgType.OrganizationTypeText,
                    Value = orgType.OrganizationTypeValue.ToString(),
                    Selected = orgSI != null
                }
               ).ToList();
```

Which the LeftJoin Method can be write as

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> LeftJoin<TSource, TInner, TKey, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
                                                     IEnumerable<TInner> inner,
                                                     Func<TSource, TKey> pk,
                                                     Func<TInner, TKey> fk,
                                                     Func<TSource, TInner, TResult> result)
    {
        return from s in source
               join i in inner
               on pk(s) equals fk(i) into joinData
               from left in joinData.DefaultIfEmpty()
               select result(s, left);
    }
```

Comment: Where can I find LeftJoin extension method?

Comment: @TorbjörnHansson updated in the answer, sorry missed out :)